# Running transformers predictions on CPU with multiprocessing

Tags: pytorch, python-multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use pre-trained model from transformers to predict on CPU with multiprocessing. Below code code gets stuck at step-4. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
I referred to below but no luck:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html

```py
import os
import torch
from transformers import BertForQuestionAnswering
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process, set_start_method

def answer_question(question, answer_text, model, tokenizer):
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(question, answer_text)
    print('Query has {:,} tokens.\n'.format(len(input_ids)))
    sep_index = input_ids.index(tokenizer.sep_token_id)
    print(".. step -- 1")
    num_seg_a = sep_index + 1
    print(".. step -- 2")
    num_seg_b = len(input_ids) - num_seg_a
    print(".. step -- 3")
    segment_ids = [0]*num_seg_a + [1]*num_seg_b
    print(".. step -- 4")
    assert len(segment_ids) == len(input_ids)
    # ======== Evaluate ========
    # Run our example question through the model.
    start_scores, end_scores = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]), # The tokens representing our input text.
                                    token_type_ids=torch.tensor([segment_ids])) # The segment IDs to differentiate question from answer_text
    print(".. step -- 5")
    # ======== Reconstruct Answer ========
    # Find the tokens with the highest `start` and `end` scores.
    answer_start = torch.argmax(start_scores)
    answer_end = torch.argmax(end_scores)
    print(".. step -- 6")
    tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
    print(".. step -- 7")
    answer = tokens[answer_start]
    print(".. step -- 8")
    for i in range(answer_start + 1, answer_end + 1):
        if tokens[i][0:2] == '##':
            answer += tokens[i][2:]
        else:
            answer += ' ' + tokens[i]
    print('Answer: "' + answer + '"')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = 2
    processes = []
    print("reading bert model")
    bert_model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')
    print("reading bert tokenizer")
    bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad')
    q_list = ["How many parameters does BERT-large have?","How many parameters does BERT-large have?"]
    a_list = ["BERT-large is really big... it has 24-layers and an embedding size of 1,024, for a total of 340M parameters! Altogether it is 1.34GB, so expect it to take a couple minutes to download to your Colab instance.", "BERT-large is really big... it has 24-layers and an embedding size of 1,024, for a total of 340M parameters! Altogether it is 1.34GB, so expect it to take a couple minutes to download to your Colab instance."]   

    for a in zip(q_list, a_list):
        print(a)
        q = Process(target = answer_question, args= (a[0], a[1], bert_model, bert_tokenizer))
        q.start()
        processes.append(q)

    for q in processes:
        q.join()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't get stuck in my environment and completes without an issue. Do you get an error message or is it just stuck? What hardware do you use (RAM, CPU)?